# how to start two threads (almost) simultaneously?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have this block in rufus

```
def download(log_message)
  $logger.info(log_message)
  download_all_from_config()
end

scheduler.in '5s' do
  first = Thread.new(download("starting cron job (in 5s mode)"))
  sleep(55)
  second = Thread.new(download("starting 2nd cron job (in 5s mode)"))
  first.join
  second.join
end
```

and what I want is to run download_all_from_config() function twice almost simultaneously. This function is downloading big files so I do not want to wait till the fist one finishes. I thought I would use threads but I cannot make it work.

Could someone suggest how to run download_all_from_config() twice so it starts almost simultaneously?

Comment: You need to call `Thread.new` with a block. Is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: @matt: no, it wasn't typo. It started the 1st thread though. Do you want to create answer from your comment so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call Thread.new with a block. i.e instead of `Thread.new(...)` you need either

```
Thread.new { ... }
```

or

```
Thread.new do
  ...
end
```

Comment: @Radek You're just passing the return value of `download` to the `Thread` constructor. You are in other words not running the two calls to `download` in parallell.

Comment: so the second download would start after the first one finished?

Comment: hmm, so if Thread.new{} is the correct syntax how come Thread.new() doesn't throw an error?

Comment: @Radek `Thread.new()` does throw an error for me. I assumed this was what you were seeing when you said it didn’t work. What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13) [armle-linux-gnu]` I start ruby with nohup so maybe I missed the error. I was not looking for error because the download started. Just the second one did not start as I wanted.

Comment: @Radek that would explain it. The first call to `download` would be evaluated (and run to completion) before Ruby tries to initialize the Thread, which is when the exception would be thrown.